# React input onchange simulation not updating value using Jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, single-page-application, enzyme

I have a functional component as below

```
const Input = () => {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      id="input"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        updateValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Input;
```

and test as below

```
const event = { target: { value: "Q" } };
input.simulate("change", event);
expect(input.prop("value")).toBe("Q");
```

the problem is that simulation of the event is not updating state.
I tried wrapper.update() as well but it is not working.

you can run test  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/input-unit-test-enzyme-9mtfe)

Comment: Besides the @skyboyer answer, you should also have a look at https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro which simplifies very much the testing of components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After component updated your `input` variable still points on old wrapper.

Wrappers(except root one) are immutable so you need to `.find()` element again.

So if you

```
const event = { target: { value: "Q" } };
input.simulate("change", event);
expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("value")).toBe("Q");
```

you will get it passed.

PS probably it's safer always avoid using intermediate variables while testing with Enzyme.

Comment: it works. but when i findby id and if i have more than one lnput i am getting error like this in sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/input-unit-test-enzyme-2lp7i @skyboyer

Comment: You are instantiating two inputs with `id="1"` and `id="2"` but looking with selector `"#heart"`.

Comment: sorry even with heart. i changed to heart

Comment: so your 3rd party component renders as `<Input .... id="heart">
  <input .... id="heart" />
</Input>`. You may see it by yourselves with `console.log(input.debug())`. What can you do? You can more specific(`.find("input#heart")`) or take just first element(`.find("#heart").at(0)`). Or you may use `shallow()` instead of `mount()`. Or you may switch to `react-testing-library`(it uses different approach)

Answer (score 1):

For those who got multiple inputs just like @NishamMahsin's case.
I had the same issue and found the working solution from [wrapper not updated after simulate('change'). #1999](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1999#issuecomment-491634796)

In short:

```
.simulate('change', {target: {name: 'inputFirstName', value: 'value'}})
```

It took me quite a long time on this, so hope it helps someone here...

Comment: It depends on the function handler that will update the state. In the case of your answer, it's like `objState[event.target.name] = event.target.value`. Hence you should Stub the Event object to match the appropriate usage of your State Setter.