# Enzyme - test prop method of a child component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a parent component `AssignCandidate` and a child component `Table`. I would like to test the Table props method. I have tried to do this like this:

```
it('Deletes assignment', async () => {
    const container = mount(<AssignCandidate />);
    await waitUntil(() => container.state('classes') !== []);
    const table = container.find(Table);
    container.setState({ candidate: candidate});
    expect(container.state('candidate')).to.eq(Candidate);
    table.props().deleteAssignment(8);
    await waitForExpect(() => expect(container.state('candidate')).to.deep.property('assignments', []));
});
```

But, I get an error:

> Error: Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

How can make this work and test child components props methods with Enzyme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React input onchange simulation not updating value using Jest and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129563/react-input-onchange-simulation-not-updating-value-using-jest-and-enzyme)

Comment: just don't save `.find()` results into variable since it will never be updated after re-rendering.

Comment: But, I don't get update issues, I get an error that 0 nodes have been found.

Comment: is `Table` present on initial rendering?

Comment: Yes, it is present